# How to understand AVPlayerItem and it's Current Time in Relation to AVPlayerItemVideoOutput

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset

I am trying to use an AVPlayerItem and AVPlayerItemVideoOutput to grab frame images of a video.  Most examples I see attach a CADisplayLink and simply pass the time of the display link to the itemTime function that exists on AVPlayerItemVideoOutput or they pass CACurrentMediaTime() instead.

```
let itemTime = playerItemVideoOutput.itemTime(forHostTime: CACurrentMediaTime())
```

The problem with this to me is I would like to grab a specific second of the video.  In most functions if have seen you could simply build a time and get that frame. For Example:

```
CMTime(seconds: 10.0, preferredTimescale: 600)//10 seconds
```

However, this is not the way AVPlayerItemVideoOutput works.  It seems to calculate it's own time from some reference point(probably when it is added and available on the player).  I need help understanding the time it needs to pass a specific frame to get of the video.

```
 //get item time so that I can grab a specific frame of the video
if playerItemVideoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime), 
   let pixelBuffer = playerItemVideoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime,itemTimeForDisplay: nil) ,
   case let i = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer){
 }
```

Some might suggest to use AVAssetImageGenerator instead and this does work but I have bound the speed and efficient of the AVPlayerItemVideoOutput to be superior to grab the number of frames that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try calling `player.seek(to:)` and then `copyPixelBuffer` with `CACurrentMediaTime()`.

But I don't know how successful you're going to be if the player is playing from some point and you try to get pixel buffers from other points in the timeline.
I don't think `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` is meant to be for truly "random access". It probably (reasonably) assumes that time will progress in the same way that it does for its `AVPlayerItem`.

Using an `AVAssetReader` with an `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` however would let you seek relative to the asset's timeline by setting the reader's `timeRange` property.

Comment: Currently I don’t have the player playing. So seeking might work although I may try an AVAssetReader to do what I want. Let me test and I will get back on this.

Comment: So given the criteria I think the AVReader is correct in terms of how I think I asked the question although I do not find it any more efficient than AVAssetImageGenerator. I ended up using AVVideoCompositing to do what I needed but really there was no clear fit for the task I was attempting.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention efficiency. I imagined that `AVAssetImageGenerator` might redundantly copy the pixel data pixel data, but I have no proof of that at all. OTOH `AVReader`'s output can be piped directly into a texture. Depends on what you want to do, and in any case you'd have to measure the performance!

Comment: Actually I think the `AVAssetImageGenerator` must involve a conversion to RGB if the `AVPlayer` is using a YUV pipeline, in which case `AVAssetReader` would "win", but then you've got two decoders happening which isn't great.